# AngularJS angular-ui-router.min.js breaks app when BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true

Tags: angularjs, minify, angularjs-ng-route, system.web.optimization

I have a very simple project in AngularJS 1.7.5 (and tried 6).

I am using system.web.optimization to do my bundling.

When running the project with optimization turned off it works fine.

When I turn on optimizations I get errors presumably from the injection/minification:

> Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error

I have removed virtuall everything from the project and when I put a breakpoint in angular.js on errors,  the last injection I see happening before I get an error is ngRoute.

I have tried multiple versions,  and including the already minified versions.

I have used $inject on everything I can see in my project that would need it.

I have used this project multiple times in older versions of angular. (pre 1.5) and it has worked.

I have stepped through the error handling and it always seems to break on ngRoute or ui-router.  Even when including the minified versions.

When I remove the scripts I get different errors (obviously) that the modules are not included.

This project is so simple I can not imagine I am having issues with the /pages/home javascript.

When running locally or published,  I get the same error when optimization is turned on, so I am fairly certain this is a minification issue I just can't for the life of me figure out why it is happening.

```
'use strict';

angular
.module("rpApp", ['ngRoute', 'ui.router'])

.config(function ($routeProvider, $urlRouterProvider,  $locationProvider) 
{
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
    $urlRouterProvider
        .otherwise('/home');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
.run(['$http', function ($http) {
}]);

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            Home Page Using Bootstrap
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>

(function () {
  angular
    .module("rpApp")
    .controller('homeController', homeController);
     homeController.$inject = [];

  function homeController() {
    var vm = this;
  }
})();

(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular.module("rpApp")
    .directive('home', homeDirective);
    homeDirective.$inject = [];

  function homeDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        require: '?ngModel',
        controller: 'homeController',
        controllerAs: 'homeVm',
        templateUrl: "App/pages/home/home.html",
        link: function (scope, elm, atts, c) {
            //dom manipulation goes in the link function
        }
    };
  };
})();

(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('rpApp')
    .config(configRouteHome);

  configRouteHome.$inject = [
    '$routeProvider',
    '$locationProvider'
  ];

  function configRouteHome($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            template: '<div data-home></div>'              
        })
        .when('/home', {
            template: '<div data-home></div>'              
        });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }
})();

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>   
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/@uirouter/angularjs/release/angular-ui- router.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ngRoute.min.js"></script>

<%: System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/angular") %>
<base href="/">
  </head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div ng-view ng-cloak></div>
  </div>
</body>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace Angular1._7
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new 
ScriptBundle("~/Bundles/angular").IncludeDirectory("~/app", "*.js", 
true));
            bundles.Add(new 
StyleBundle("~/Bundles/css").IncludeDirectory("~/app", "*.css", true));

            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the project to bundle and minify with these bare minimum of components added. (ui-router and ng-route) but instead it never seems to reach the /app

Comment: Nat Wallbank was right.  I missed the config portion.  I had copied one from another project to add pretty urls.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your config function parameters will still be minified?

You'll need to either use the array injection syntax (as you've done for your run method) or use $inject.

Comment: You were right.  I missed it in the config portion.  Thanks for your time.